# Excel: Aggregate formula with multiple (date) criteria and If-statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, aggregate

I have a large list of clients that have an appointment on 4 different occassions (I call this Subjects): 1st Visit, 1st check up, 2nd check up and final visit. These clients are also linked to a partner: Kate, Dave, Bart, Will, John and Tom.

From this large list of clients I want to be able to extract client names based "Subject" and "Partner" between two dates (for example 1st of January and 1st of March). So I have made the two following dropdown lists:

Subject: No selection, 1st Visit, 1st Check up, 2nd Check up and Final Visit.

Partner: No selection, Kate, Dave, Bart, Will, John and Tom.

So for example if I choose to view all the clients that have an appointment between the 1st of January 2019 and 1st of March 2019, "Subject = 1st Visit" and "Partner = No selection". I want to be able to see all the appointments for the 1st Visit, for all the partners between the above two dates. And if I select the above to dates, "Subject = No selection" and "Partner = No Selection" I want to be able to see all the appointments between the two selected dates for all the subjects and all the partners.

I'm having the following 2 problems in my Excel sheet.

**First**
I'm using the countifs formula (G6 in excel sheet Extract") to count the amount of appointments. But the trouble that I'm having with this is that I cannot seem to correctly write the formula to also count the partners and the "No selection" part. The countifs formula that I have now only counts the subject between two dates, so whenever I select "No selection" for the subject it doesn't give me a count for everything (like I would want it to).

**Second**
My Aggregate formula (G10 in excel sheet "Extract") is a mess, I have to little knowledge to write the formula correctly. I would greatly appreciate any help with this. I think the aggregate function is beautiful, if anyone has got any tips to where I can learn more about this I would also greatly appreciate it.

Link to my excel sheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqntzkj2xq0i250/Aggregate%20function%20struggle.xlsx?dl=0

I know it's the Holidays, perhaps not the best time to ask a question online but these formulas are like a splinter in my mind right now.

Comment: Not sure about your second question - would you like to list all Clients that match your filter criteria (i.e. dates, subject, partner)? Taking 1/1/2019-31/12/2019, 1st Visit and Dave as an example, would you like to see a list of 6 client names?

Comment: Yes exactly. The actual client list is very long and by extracting with the selected criteria I would want to see only what is needed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I edited my answer (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you with your **first** question.

In EXTRACTED tab, cell G6, paste the following formula:

=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("source[[#All],["&$L$5&"]]"),">="&$G$4,INDIRECT("source[[#All],["&$L$5&"]]"),"<="&$N$4,source[[#All],[PARTNER]],IF($J$5="No Selection","<>""",$J$5))

As for your **second** question, you need to unmerge cells G10:L64 in EXTRACTED tab (as Array formulas are not valid in merged cells). In cell G10, use the following Array formula (confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

=IFERROR(INDEX(source[[#All],[NAME]],(SMALL(IF((--(INDIRECT("source[[#All],["&$L$5&"]]")>=EXTRACTED!$G$4))*(--(INDIRECT("source[[#All],["&$L$5&"]]")<=EXTRACTED!$N$4))*IF($J$5="No Selection",1,(--(source[[#All],[PARTNER]]=EXTRACTED!$J$5))),ROW(source[[#All],[NAME]]),""),F10))),"")

You can now drag it down to see all results. I know you wanted to use AGGREGATE formula but I followed my solution (sorry!). Once the formula is entered, you can now select cells G10:L10 and click on "Merge & Center".

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are so beautiful, this works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it works! I will check your second question and reply today.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working perfectly. You're a treasure! Can't thank you enough.